# check file exists or not using regular expression in ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a folder which contains many files. Now I have to check file with specific name exists or not.

For checking file existence I have used `File.exists?` method. For example

```
File.exists? ("/home/ubuntu/vga2usb.sql")
 => true
```

but sometimes filename contains timestamps (e.g. 20140707_vga2usb.sql). I think I have to use regular expression for it.
So I tired with

```
   File.exists?("/home/ubuntu/*_vga2usb")
   => false
```

Is there any other way for checking file existence.
 Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
!Dir.glob("/yourpattern/*.sql").empty?
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Dir` or `Dir.glob` http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Dir.html

Here:

```
Dir["/home/ubuntu/*_vga2usb"]

Dir.glob("/home/ubuntu/*_vga2usb")
```