# Use regular expression in assert_file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I would like to test that there exists a file whose name contains a certain string.

The file should be in the following format:

`db/migrate/(timestamp)_migration.rb`

where (timestamp) is a bunch of digits (e.g. 20141010081656).

I have tried to use string interpolation with `Regexp` to match this file within `assert_file` with no success.

`assert_file "db/migrate/#{Regexp.new('.+')}_migration.rb"`

Any suggestions?

Comment: use `\d+` as pattern?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I get `Expected file "db/migrate/(?-mix:\\d+)_migration.rb" to exist, but does not`. When I check the file manually, it exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mention a "certain string"--is there really no way to make the filename more of a "known," for testing purposes?

Otherwise, check out:

[check file exists or not using regular expression in ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24752299/check-file-exists-or-not-using-regular-expression-in-ruby)

Which might translate to:

```
assert !Dir.glob("db/migrate/*_migration.rb").empty?
```